# How to deal with ExecutionCondition if i want to disable test, if some annotation present below the test method?

Tags: java, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

Currently trying JUnit five and want to implement into my automation framework possibility skip tests if my custom annotation present.

If im trying to do like:

```
public class KnownIssueExtension implements ExecutionCondition {


    @Override
    public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(ExtensionContext context) {
    if(context.getRequiredTestMethod().isAnnotationPresent(KnownIssue.class)){
        return disabled("HERE DISABLED");
//        if(context.getTestMethod().isPresent(element -> findAnnotation(element, KnownIssue.class))){
     } else return enabled("enabled");
    }
}
```

im receiving such exception:

```
org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluationException: Failed to evaluate condition [org.talend.qa.iam.utils.KnownIssueExtension]: Illegal state: required test method is not present in the current ExtensionContext
```

But another method like:

```
context.getTestMethod
```

doesn't have any checks if annotation present.

Could anyone pointing me out what i'am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the APIs have changed since, but I wanted to do something similar when initially testing JUnit 5.  (See [here](https://github.com/BeUndead/junit-common/blob/master/fail/src/main/java/com/com/fail/ExpectedFailure.java).)

Sorry for just code dumping, but it seems simple enough that it probably is fairly self-explanatory:

```
public final class KnownIssueExtension implements TestExecutionExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleTestExecutionException(final TestExtensionContext context,
                                             final Throwable throwable) 
            throws Exception {

        final Method testMethod = context.getTestMethod().get();
        if (!testMethod.isAnnotationPresent(KnownIssue.class)) {
            throw throwable;
        }
    }
}
```

(Note: untested, even for compilation.)

Edit:

---

Oh, I only just noticed *skip*, not ignore the failure.  In which case does something like your commented out code not work:

```
final Optional<Method> methodOptional = context.getTestMethod();
if (methodOptional.isPresent()
        && methodOptional.get().isAnnotationPresent(KnownIssue.class)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: hell yeah, now it's working, thatnks that you pointing out me in a obvious thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:

```
public class KnownIssueExtension implements ExecutionCondition {

@Override
public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(ExtensionContext context) {

    final Optional<Method> methodOptional = context.getTestMethod();
    if (methodOptional.isPresent()
            && methodOptional.get().isAnnotationPresent(KnownIssue.class)) {
        return disabled("DISABLED");
    }
    return enabled("ENABLED");
}
```

}